Moduli space of curves away from singular subsets
Recently, I'm interested in the moduli spaces of curves in a (possibly noncompact) complex orbifold (resp. symplectic and almost complex) away from singularities.
More specifically, I'm interested in the compactification process of such moduli space under the simple case $X/G$ where $X$ is a symplectic manifold, and $G$ is a finite group acting on $X$ such that $(X/G)^{\mathrm{smooth}}$ is still a symplectic manifold.
Are there some well-founded references or papers for this?
